# Blurred sprite in Scene view

Tags: unity, rendering, sprites

The thread between the tree and the spider here is a `LineRenderer`.

When the `BackgroundLandscape` or the `Tree` objects are selected it has this blur around the thread between the tree and the spider.

[image: Tree selected]

When anything else is selected, it renders correctly.

[image: Nest Selected]

It always renders correctly in the Game view.

[image: Imgur]

What's causing this?

Comment: That looks like the selection outline that Unity draws around your selected object so you can see what you're editing. Have you tried toggling this off in the [Gizmos menu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory I thought it was that because it looked suspiciously like it.  I think it was a bug though, it's just disappeared.